# Sending an email in HTML and plain with a Gmail Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I'm writing an auto-replying bot for gmail using Google Apps Script (http://script.google.com). Each time I use `GmailThread`'s [`Reply`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#replybody-options) to reply to message:

```
var htmlbody = "Hello<br>This is a <b>test</b>.<br>Bye.";
var body = "Hello,\nThis is a test.\nBye.";

thread.reply(body, {htmlBody: htmlbody, from: "Myself <hello@example.com>"});
```

I need to write the message both in plain text `body` and HTML in `htmlbody`.

**Would there be a way to write an email only in HTML** (to avoid writing every email content twice, plain and HTML!), **and let `reply()` automatically send the email both in HTML and plaintext version?**

---

I tried

```
var body = htmlbody.replace(/<br>/g,'\n').replace(/<b>/g,''); 
// we should also replace </b> by '', etc.
```

but this is a bit of a hack. Is there a better version?

Answer (score 1):

Google Scripts cannot generate the plain text portion automatically but you write a simple regex based replaces that removes all the tags from the HTML for plain text.

```
var body = htmlBody.replace(/<.+?>/g, "");
thread.reply(body, {htmlBody: htmlbody, from: "Myself <hello@example.com>"});
```

Also, if you set the body to blank, most modern email clients would still be able to render the image.

Comment: Thanks, so this confirms we have to do it manually and `reply` cannot do it for us. Maybe `htmlbody.replace(/<br>/g,'\n').replace(/<.+?>/g, "");` would be useful as well?